# Why is my command failing?

Tags: bash, sed, find

```
for i in `find `pwd` -name .htaccess -exec grep -q "RedirectMatch" {} \; -print`; do $i | sed -i 's/RedirectMatch/#RedirectMatch/g'; done
```

So pretty much my command should search for all the .htaccess files and grep the ones that have "RedirectMatch" in them, once that's done it should be piped to sed to comment out the line.

Running

```
find `pwd` -name .htaccess -exec grep -q "RedirectMatch" {} \; -print
```

Actually gives me a list of the .htaccess files with "RedirectMatch" in them, but when I run it in my loop it throws a huge list of files, even ones that are not named .htaccess.

Any ideas? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong with that command:

First, you need to escape the nested-backticks for them to work the way you think they are working:

```
`find \`pwd\` -name .htaccess -exec grep -q "RedirectMatch" {} \; -print`
```

or use the preferred subshell notation:

```
$(find $(pwd) -name .htaccess -exec grep -q "RedirectMatch" {} \; -print)
```

Second, you cannot pipe into `sed` while using the in-place `-i` flag. I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish here, but I think you should just run `sed` on each file, if the string isn't there, nothing will be replaced, and it wont be any less efficient. What you are doing does not edit any files in any way, you're just running `sed` on the filenames from stdin, not the files themselves! So something like this:

```
find . -name .htaccess -exec sed -i "" 's/RedirectMatch/#RedirectMatch/g' {} \;
```

NOTE: The quotes after the `-i` are necessary for my `sed` (running on darwin), they satisfy the `-i` flag's need for an argument, probably not needed for most `sed`s. Also as someone else mentioned, the call to `pwd` is not necessary, so I swapped that with `.`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your backticks: your command actually executed `find`, then appends the `pwd` string to it and then tries and execute the rest.

Use `$(...)`:

```
for i in $(find $(pwd) -name .htaccess -exec grep -q "RedirectMatch" {} \; -print); do sed -i 's/RedirectMatch/#RedirectMatch/g' $i; done
```

And since by default `find` looks up in the current directory by default if none as specified, you can specify it further:

```
for i in $(find -name .htaccess -exec grep -q "RedirectMatch" {} \; -print); do sed -i 's/RedirectMatch/#RedirectMatch/g' $i; done
```

(edit: also fixed the invocation of the sed command)

Comment: Or better yet, trade `find .` for `find $(pwd)` and save a process.

Comment: In this case, might as well drop the directory argument completely ;) By default, `find` looks up in the current directory.

Comment: Your `sed` command is wonky, though; you mean `... do sed 's/RedirectMatch/#RedirectMatch/' "$i"; done` where the substitution could furthermore be abbreviated to `#&`.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it. (the `-i` substitutes directly in its argument).

Comment: GNU find defaults to the current directory, but some other implementations will not allow you to omit the directory.

Comment: Well, there is the linux tag, the chances of it not being GNU find are therefore very close to 0 ;)

Comment: Using string-splitting to split find results like this will fail badly whenever you encounter a file with whitespace in its name.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given here thus far are dangerously wrong -- they can be manipulated to contain arbitrary output (think of someone creating a single file with spaces in its name, such as `"./ /etc/passwd /.htaccess"`, and thus causing your script to edit `/etc/passwd`).

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  sed -i -e 's/^([^#]+)RedirectMatch/\1#RedirectMatch/' "$filename"
done < <(find . -name .htaccess -print0)
```

Note, however, that using `sed -i` isn't portable -- the `-i` flag isn't specified in POSIX, and many operating systems don't support it. You'd do better to use `ex` for the editing, which is specified by POSIX and uses the same syntax for editing as the command mode in `vi`:

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  ex "$filename" -s - <<<'%s/^\([^#]*\)RedirectMatch/\1#RedirectMatch/'$'\n''x'
done < <(find . -name .htaccess -print0)
```